# Determining the limit of a series given the sum.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Say we have an unknown infinite series $\{Q_n\}$, and we are given that the sum of $\{Q_n\}$ is $23$. We are then asked to determine the limit of $Q_n$ as $n$ approaches infinity. Does anyone know how I could solve this?

Comment: You have solved your own question.

Comment: I think you're saying that you have an infinite sequence (not series), $\{Q_n \mid n \in \Bbb N \}$ and the sum of the sequence exists and is $23$.  You want to know $\lim_{n \to \infty} Q_n$.  Is that right?

Comment: If a series converges then the limit of the defyining sequence is zero. This is a classic Analysis 1 theorem and can be proven by contradiction.

Comment: @b00nheT It can be proven more directly that using contradiction. Juste write $$Q_N =\left(\sum_{k=1}^N Q_k \right)-\left(\sum_{k=1}^{N-1} Q_k \right)$$
and let $N$ tend to $+\infty$.